# Fancybox: how to scroll HTML fragments instead of images with the same effect?

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

**I would like to show HTML fragments instead of images with the same scrolling effect (when we call the next() method).**

I can't realize how to make it working. We can show fancybox with a single html fragment:

```
$.fancybox( htmlFragment );
```

But I would like several fragments. How to force the lib. to use HTML fragments instead of images?

Why I do need it: I have to create a pop-up wizard with several forms.

Comment: when you say "scroll fragments" do you mean, a gallery of html blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have your html fragments as `inline` content

```
<div style="display: none">
    <div id="section1">
        <h1>Section One</h1>
        ...content
    </div>
    <div id="section2">
        <h1>Section Two</h1>
        ...content
    </div>
    <div id="section3">
        <h1>Section Three</h1>
        ...content
    </div>

    ... etc
</div>
```

and link to each section like

```
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="#section1">open section one</a>
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="#section2">open section two</a>
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="#section3">open section three</a>
```

Notice that all links share the same `rel` attribute.

Then use a simple fancybox script

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uFTxu/)**